# Uptodate (2020) ways of retrieving live and historical stock data to Excel/VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, stock, stockquotes

I am researching methods for getting stock data to Excel via VBA. Most of the tutorials and articles about it seem to use googlefinance, however, I would like to know other methods and possibly the most recommended one for creating a spreadsheet with live and historical stock data.
Thanks !
(Office 2019 User)

Answer (score 2):

For Excel 365

Select the *Data* tab in the Ribbon

Place **LMT** in a cell *(or any stock you choose)*

Touch the <kbd>Stocks</kbd> button in the Ribbon

Touch `Select` in the Dialog.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I forgot to mention that I use MS Office 2019 so I don't have this option available. It would be pretty easy to go with that one thou.